# What's wrong with this XPath query?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, rss

I'm trying to select nodes from an rss feed.  It works fine for Twitter, but I can't do it on Youtube.

```
        string youtube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CTVOlympics/uploads";
        string twitter = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/ctvolympics.rss";

        //this populates the XmlNodeList object
        XmlTextReader readerTwitter = new XmlTextReader(twitter);
        XmlDocument docTwitter = new XmlDocument();
        docTwitter.Load(readerTwitter);
        XmlNodeList nodesTwitter = docTwitter.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

        //this doesn't populate the object
        XmlTextReader readerYoutube = new XmlTextReader(youtube);
        XmlDocument docYoutube = new XmlDocument();
        docYoutube.Load(readerYoutube);
        XmlNodeList nodesYoutube = docYoutube.SelectNodes("/feed/entry");
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is this .NET 1.1? If not, then you should be using `XmlReader.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextReader()`. Also, post some of the XML you're trying to read.

Comment: thanks John Saunders, that was incredibly helpful.  The xml feeds are and were linked above, so perhaps you didn't read the question.  Anybody who truly wanted to help rather than simply read their own text probably would have left a more helpful comment

Comment: @codemonkey12: that's all I had time for. And the comment is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to select the node 'entry' in an empty namespace, whereas you should be trying to select the node 'entry' in the namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'.

You can use `XMLNamespaceManager` to specify a default namespace:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(docYoutube.NameTable);
nsmanager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
```

or you could use `"/*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']"`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the namespace.

Comment: See XmlNode..::.SelectNodes Method (String, XmlNamespaceManager) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualize the result of XPath queries, you can use the [XpathVisualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com). 
It's a WinForms tool.  Load the XML document you want to query, key in the query, view the results.

[image]

Free.  Open source.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not generate an error, it must be because the xml-document doesn't contain a `<feed>`-element, or `<entry>` elements with a `<feed>`-parent.

Comment: I was really hoping that everyone who cared enough to help would actually look at the xml I left so silly "answers" like this wouldn't be given.

Comment: @codemonkey12: this is a correct answer. It does not have a (namespace-qualified) `feed` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting at the base of the problem by using the // instead of /. So something like //entry my work better as it will plumb the depths looking for your request.

But my question is whether that XPath query is actually retrieving anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
string youtube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CTVOlympics/uploads";
string twitter = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/ctvolympics.rss";

//this populates the XmlNodeList object
XmlDocument docTwitter;
using (var readerTwitter = XmlReader.Create(twitter))
{
    docTwitter = new XmlDocument();
    docTwitter.Load(readerTwitter);
}
XmlNodeList nodesTwitter = docTwitter.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

//this doesn't populate the object
XmlDocument docYoutube;
using (var readerYoutube = XmlReader.Create(youtube))
{
    docYoutube = new XmlDocument();
    docYoutube.Load(readerYoutube);
}
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(docYoutube.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
XmlNodeList nodesYoutube = docYoutube.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry", ns);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:  `"/*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry']"`